# Remover extensão do arquivo, para não ser vista pelo usuário

Tags: php, htaccess

Como eu faria para que a extensão do arquivo não fosse vista pelo usuário?

#### Exemplo

Assim que o usuário terminar o cadastro, ele vai ser direcionado para a página `confirmacao.php`, porém gostaria de que a extensão `.php` não fosse visível, apenas `confirmacao/`. Entendo que isto é **Url amigáveis** e pode ser feito pelo `.htaccess`, mas como posso aplicar em todas as páginas?

- `contato.php` => `contato/`
- `cadastro.php` => `cadastro/`
- etc.

Isso é possível? Ou eu teria que criar um diretório para cada página?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No meu .htaccess eu utilizo este trecho de código para retirar o .php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

### Explicação

- `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` - vai verificar a partir do diretorio `ROOT` + `o "arquivo" da url solicitada` (quer disser que exclui as QueryString)

#### Exemplo

- Seu site esta em `/www/` (Diretório `ROOT` de projeto)
- A url solicitada é `domain.com/contato?name=Guilherme`
- `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` será `/www/contato`

#### Retomando

- Na regra `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` diz : Pegue este caminho (`/www/contato`) adicione `.php` e verifique se é um arquivo `-f` (file)
- Caso verdadeiro aplicar a regra abaixo
- `!.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` - Caso não tenha `.php` no final, adicionar, mantendo as configurações de QueryString `[QSA]`.

Mesmo que a regra esteja dizendo adicionar `.php` no final isso é um configuração interna, para o PHP identificar o arquivo, o usuário nem sabe que isso ocorre.

Comment: Me permite explica o que isso faz?

Comment: Perfeito Pedro Morais. Funcionou corretamente. Obrigado!

Comment: Claro, se quiser complementar a resposta fique a vontade =)

Comment: Se não ficou bem clara a explicação, me avisar para melhorar

Comment: Muito boa a explicação Guilherme. Obrigado.